# recommended heat tape for PEX piping

Tags: plumbing

living in Maine, where temps can run minus zero for days on end, i feel that I need more than insulation to keep my PEX pipe running from my pressure tank to the main line underneath my mobile home from freezing. Regarding safety, are there special requirements or listings/certifications for heat tape to be used with PEX?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=pex+tubing+%22heat+tape%22